# How to convert string to object

Tags: ruby, reflection, polymorphism

I have the following method to read a JSON file and convert it to a `Question` object:

```
def self.deserializeQuestions(json)
  if json.nil?
  else
    data = JSON.parse(json)
    questions = Hash.new
    data['questions'].map do |q|
      questions[q['id']] = Question.new(q['id'], q['questionText'])
    end
  end
end
```

The JSON contains questions of different types that correspond to different classes. The types are `'multichoice'`, `'truefalse'`, etc., and the classes are `MultichoiceQuestion`, `TrueFalseQuestion`, etc. All of them inherit from `Question` that still have `id` and `questionText`.

Here is an example of the JSON file I'm using:

```
{ "questions": 
   [
     {
       "type": "multichoice", 
       "id" : 1,
       "questionText": "Scala is...",
        "alternatives": [
           { "text": "alternative 1", "code": 1, "value": 1 },
           { "text": "alternative 2", "code": 2, "value": -0.25 },
           { "text": "alternative 3", "code": 3, "value": -0.25 }
        ]
     },
     {
       "type" : "truefalse",
       "id" : 2,
       "questionText": "Ruby creator is Yukihiro Matsumoto",
       "correct": true,
       "valueOK": 1,
       "valueFailed": -0.25,
     }
   ]
}
```

How can I modify this code to be able to create specific types of `Question` based on the attribute type?

Comment: How would you understand when to make which class objects... You need to provide some more informations..

Comment: I edited the question with an example of the JSON file used.

Comment: You have not mentioned `questionId` in JSON you're parsing. Are you sure it's `questionId` and not `id`?

Comment: Yeah, that was wrong. Fixed. Sorry

Comment: Is the type of Questions are fixed?

Comment: Okay let me think.. to give you some idea..

Comment: What is alternatives?

Comment: @Surya possible answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is what, I would model your problem using [`Struct`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Struct.html) -

```
  hash = { "questions" => 
         [
           {
             "type" => "multichoice", 
             "id" => 1,
             "questionText" => "Scala is...",
           },
           {
             "type" => "truefalse",
             "id" => 2,
             "questionText" => "Ruby creator is Yukihiro Matsumoto",
           }
         ]
      }

questions = hash['questions'].map do |inner_hash| 
  Struct.new(inner_hash['type'].capitalize, :id, :question_text).new(*inner_hash.values_at('id', 'questionText'))
end

questions
# => [#<struct Struct::Multichoice id=1, question_text="Scala is...">,
#     #<struct Struct::Truefalse
#      id=2,
#      question_text="Ruby creator is Yukihiro Matsumoto">]

questions.map(&:values)
# => [[1, "Scala is..."], [2, "Ruby creator is Yukihiro Matsumoto"]]
```

Comment: I think that this has the same problem that in the answer above. I need to have the exact type of the question to be able to set its specific values. In the case of a truefalse question the JSON contains the correct answer (true false) that I must store in the object. The same occurs with other types of questions whose have their own attributes. Sorry, was my fault. I simplified the JSON too much.

Comment: I think `Struct` is the way to solve your problem.. You edit your post again, if I can, I will try to help you next when I will again available in SO.

Comment: Edited. I added some more properties. I solved this problem with if blocks but I was looking for a more elegant code. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Nice answer, and then Struct can be used to create questions based on the attributes it has, right?

Comment: @Surya  Yes.. As the question types are _dynamic_, so `Struct` is the good way to go as per my opinion.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose the type-class correspondence is expressed as a hash

```
TypeClass = {
  "multichoice" => MultichoiceQuestion,
  "truefalse" => TrueFalseQuestion,
  ...
}
```

Then, do:

```
JSON.parse(json)["questions"].each_with_object({}) do |h, questions|
  questions[h["id"]] = TypeClass[h["type"]].new(h["id"], h["questionText"])
end
```

Comment: Yeah, that is a really nice solution but I need to know the type of question because each type has its own attributes. For example, a multichoice questions can have a fixed number of answers but a truefalse question will have only two (true and false) and only one can be valid.

Comment: @DavidMorenoGarcía I don't get what you mean by "need to know the type of question." Aren't you getting that from JSON?

Comment: I mean, in that example you create a question based in the type but after that there are more values that must to be added to the object. Myabe the JSON example is not clear enough but for example in a truefalse question I have to add the correct answer. Is it possible to create a hash with a method instead a class? That way I could create specific handlers for each type of question.